# How to have different amount of products per row, different in each page layout

Tags: magento

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/display-more-items-per-row-in-products-page

**^ This post is a guide to set 4 products per row | For all pages.**

I want to set a different amount of products for each page layout.

**THE GOAL:**

- **3 Products per row** for **3 Column-Page Layout**
- **4 Products per row** for  **2 Column ^**
- **5 Products per row** for **1 Column ^**

Please give instructions to customize products per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml (create it if you haven't by copying from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml) and replace the line:

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

with

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>

<?php

// Get the layout's page template
$pageLayoutRootTemplate = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate();
// Set the column count based on the layout template used
switch ($pageLayoutRootTemplate) {
    case 'page/1column.phtml':
        $_columnCount = 5;
        break;
    case 'page/2columns-left.phtml':
        $_columnCount = 4;
        break;
    case 'page/2columns-right.phtml':
        $_columnCount = 4;
        break;
    case 'page/3columns.phtml':
        $_columnCount = 3;
        break;
    default:
        $_columnCount = 3;
        break;
}
// comment normal line out $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>

<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

Obviously modify it to what you want.